# How to send the kerberos token from an angular app to wso2 am for retrieving the access token?

Tags: angular, kerberos, wso2-api-manager

We are using an angular application which uses a WSO2 API Manager (V2.6.0) to execute REST-Services. We are running in a Windows environment and want to use the "Kerberos OAuth2 Grant" authentication scheme of the WSO2. Now my question: How can we send the Kerberos token to the WSO2 from the angular frontend, to send the request as described in 
`curl -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic <base64-encoded-client-id>:<client-secret-value>" -k
-d
"grant_type=kerberos&kerberos_realm=<kerberos-realm>&kerberos_token=<kerberos-token>&scope=<s
cope>" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:8243/token`

We have tried to send the request without the kerberos token and expected, that the kerberos token will be added from the browser but that did not work.